# How to get inverse trigonometric functions in Eiffel?

Tags: math, trigonometry, inverse, eiffel

How do I use inverse trigonometric functions such as sin inverse, cos inverse, and tan inverse in [Eiffel](http://eiffel.org)?

I tried `atan`, `arctan`, and `arctangent`, but none of them work. I was also unable to find it in any other source.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://archive.eiffel.com/doc/online/eiffel50/intro/studio/index-09A/base/support/double_math.html

using the `double_math` class the names are `arc_sine`, `arc_cosine`, `arc_tangent`. There is no argument function like `atan2`.

Comment: A more up-to-date version can be found at [Eiffel.org](https://www.eiffel.org/files/doc/static/trunk/libraries/base/double_math_flatshort.html).

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov Thank you.